# MoeEngage Validation device could not registered

Tags: android, moengage

I am integrating MoeEngage for tacking events and attributes. I have followed the official documentation for integrating android SDK. I try to validate that moeEngage integration is working as expected.

```
// This is the instance of the application class and "XXXXXXXXXXX" is the APP ID from the dashboard.
    MoEngage moEngage = new MoEngage.Builder(this, BuildConfig.MOENGAGE_APP_ID)
            .enableSegmentIntegration()
            .setLogLevel(VERBOSE)
            .build();
    MoEngage.initialise(moEngage);
```

Event Tracking Snippet

```
/**
 * Track Event using {@linkplain MoEHelper}
 *
 * @param builderName The action name
 * @param eventParameter The event attribute name
 * @param eventValue The event attribute value
 */
public void trackDynamicEvent(String builderName, String eventParameter, String eventValue ) {
    PayloadBuilder builder = new PayloadBuilder();

    builder.putAttrString(eventParameter, eventValue);

    moEngageHeleperInstance.trackEvent(builderName, builder);
}
```

I am validating using QR code it is showing error

> The device could not be registered. Click on the button to retry

I have followed these links

https://docs.moengage.com/docs/sdk-initialization

https://docs.moengage.com/docs/track-event

For validation

https://app.moengage.com/v3/#/integration/verify/android

**Edit: Added dependency**

```
def moengageVersion = "9.7.01"
implementation "com.moengage:moe-android-sdk:$moengageVersion"
```

Comment: Can you please add the MoEngage related dependencies added to your application in the question will help me answer the question better

Comment: I have added a dependency please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue here is Segment Integration is enabled by calling `enableSegmentIntegration()`. From the dependency I see that you are using MoEngage directly not via Segment. Do not call `enableSegmentIntegration()` on the `MoEngage.Builder` and your issue should be resolved.

Comment: Yeah. This solves my problem.  API without using Segment bundle will result in a malfunction of the SDK

Comment: Uninstall graph is showing uninstall but "User Uninstalls By Attribute" is not coming can you please have a look into the given screenshot https://imgur.com/a0xt3cd

Comment: Please drop an email with the details to support@moengage.com and our customer service team will help you on this.